# Change font initial line spacing?

Tags: software-recommendation, font-design

I'm wondering, for a given font which I have the .otf file for, is it possible to adjust the fonts initial line spacing? For instance, I'm an iOS developer, and I noticed when you set a fonts line spacing to 0 within the program, it may differ from another fonts line spacing which is also set to 0. This leads me to believe that differing fonts have differing line spacing when at 0?

Are there any freeware programs out there that might let me adjust this value for my font?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/) as a free demo and possibly other software but Fontographer is the one I've used and hear of the most. In the Element menu, go to Font information in the dimensions tab. You find typographic line spacing options, ascender (top value), descender (bottom value). You will be able to test the font but because if you only get the demo it will be partially saved/watermarked.

[FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) is an open source editor you might want to look into since it's free.

If you are an iOS developer I would be careful because I'm fairly sure that you would most likely not be allowed to modify an existing font and redistribute it in an app. Contact the foundry to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mean like the space in between two lines of text. For instance, in the comment you wrote above there is a certain amount of space between the bottom of your first line (which starts with "I'm guessing") and the top of your second line (which starts with "likely be"). The font is actually a custom font that isn't included with Apple so I think I should be alright there.

Comment: Ok so you mean leading, I've edited my answer to reflect this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can change line height of font file, with this little script https://github.com/norflin321/font-lh-changer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/111976)